# структура базы данных, уникальные сочетания

Tags: java, sql, база-данных

у меня задание сделать приложение для туристической компании, среди прочего нужно хранить в базе данных список круизов, у каждого круиза есть дата начала, окончания, судно, список портов, а так же первый и последний порт

подскажите как лучше хранить список портов для круиза, они должны быть в заданном порядке, пока остановился на хранении их в виде строки и добавление новых круизов администратором, так как не придумал ничего более подходящего.
проект учебный, пишу на java сервлетах

думал сделать отдельную таблицу портов и связать с таблицей круизов связью многие ко многим, но не получилось, так как в разных круизах могут совпадать порты и даты, не получается сделать значения уникальными и в хранить в нужном порядке

```
CREATE TABLE cruise(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ship_id INT REFERENCES ship(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    departure_port_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES port(id),
    date_of_departure DATE NOT NULL,
    arrival_port_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES port(id),
    date_of_arrival DATE NOT NULL,
    route VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Список портов должен иметь такую характеристику как дата-время захода в порт. Этого достаточно для сортировки. Ну и нормализуйте данные, CSV со списком портов - это явный бред.

Comment: так один и тот же порт может быть у разных круизов записан на одну и ту же дату

Comment: *один и тот же порт может быть у разных круизов записан на одну и ту же дату* Ага, и на одно и то же время... Труффальдино, блин.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы спроектировать нормальную бд почитайте о том как это делается и обратите большое внимание на нормализацию. Когда я говорю нормальная бд - я имею в виду базу данных без дублирования данных, которая соответсвует в здравом смысле модели, учёт данных которой мы и ведём. Уверяю вас, если вы нормализуете свою бд, хотя бы до 3 нормальной формы, то у вас сразу получится то, что будет вызывать у вас приятные эмоции.